# Entire function and inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is,
let f be an entire function such that |$f(z)$| $≥$ |$z|^ {0.0037}$ for all sufficiently large $|z|$ .

Prove  that f($\mathbb{C}$) = $\mathbb{C}$.

I know Liovville Theorem i.e if $f$ is entire and bounded it is constant. and I have a hint If $ b \not\in f(C)$, consider $g(z)=(f(z)-b)^{-1}$

Then,$g(z)=(f(z)-b)^{-1}\leq(|z|^{0.0037}-b)^{-1}$ so $g$ is bounded. So it is constant by Liovville. but I don't know how to solve then.

Comment: Show that $g(z)$ would be bounded.

Comment: Why exactly $0.0037$ ?

Comment: this was given in the question but ı think it is not important

Comment: I am not sure what you want to know, you basically have the solution right there... ($f$ can not be constant under the given assumption, so neither can $g$.)

Comment: I need proof of f($\mathbb{C}$) = $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: You arrived at $\frac1{f(z)-b}=A$

Comment: Also the remaining part of the problem is to show that $\lim_{z\to \infty} |f(z)|=\infty$ implies $f$ is a polynomial.